# How to solve JsonIOException problem when i have http-request using retrofit2

Tags: android, kotlin, server, retrofit, httprequest

My project was running perfectly but suddenly show this error when i request a list from server by retrofit using GsonConverter :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
com.google.gson.JsonIOException: Interfaces can't be instantiated! Register an InstanceCreator or a TypeAdapter for this type. Interface name: retrofit2.Call
at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:136)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$FieldReflectionAdapter.createAccumulator(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:427)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:383)
at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:40)
at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:243)
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:153)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@b5910a6, Dispatchers.Main.immediate]
```

I tried cleaning project and rebuild it and also invalidate caching
but also same problem shows

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i solved this problem by deleting "suspend" keyword from my interface function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by deleting the "suspend" keyword from my interface function